# How to disable a button after enabling it with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that needs to be disabled until I have all the forms correctly filled. I can do it, but, when I enable the button, I can't disable it again when I remove any form.

Code of the button

```html
<form method="post">
 <button type="submit" id="botaoSignUp" 
 name="botaoSignUp" disabled class="login100-form-btn">
   Sign Up
 </button>
</form>
```

Code to disable/enable the button

```
if((document.getElementById("nameAviso")).textContent=="Ok"&&
(document.getElementById("emailAviso")).textContent=="Ok"&&
(document.getElementById("passAviso")).textContent=="Ok"&&
(document.getElementById("localAviso")).textContent=="Ok"){

          document.getElementById("botaoSignUp").disabled = false;
}else{
          document.getElementById("botaoSignUp").disabled = true;
}
```

Other elements

```html
<div class="wrap-input100">
                        <span class="label-input100">Full Name</span>
                            <input class="input100" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" onblur="showHint(this.value, 0)"><span id="nameAviso"></span>
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100">
                        <span class="label-input100">Email</span>
                            <input class="input100" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email addess" onblur="showHint(this.value, 1)"><span id="emailAviso"></span>
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100">
                        <span class="label-input100">Password</span>
                            <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="*************" onblur="showHint(this.value, 2)"><span id="passAviso"></span>
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100">
                        <span class="label-input100">Localidade</span>
                            <input class="input100" type="text" name="localidade" placeholder="Localidade" onblur="showHint(this.value, 3)"><span id="localAviso"></span>
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                    </div>
```

Comment: The same way you enabled it...

Comment: Could you add the other HTML fields too so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn done

Comment: @ritaj that's the problem, I try it the same way but it doesn't disable

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz? https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-8whnle

Comment: forget, the problem was because the script was inside a if that didn't enter in it, sorry for the waste of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved, was a bad algorithm where it only checked if all the form are correctly filled inside an if which wasn't entered when it should.

Answer (score 0):

You have already added the disabled attribute in your button. 
Remove the attribute and trigger it from JS when required.
Also put your statement in following function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

Comment: I suppose it's not exactly what I wanted to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Removes the "disabled" event.

```
document.getElementById("botaoSignUp").removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Adds the "disabled" event.

```
document.getElementById("botaoSignUp").setAttribute("disabled","");
```

You don't need to write anything for "disabled".